# how to store pretty urls in mysql and call them in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. Currently my urls look like this:

```
mysite/1/page-title
```

1 is the page id and I want to get rid of it so the full url would look like this:

```
mysite/page-title
```

I cannot find a good tutorial to explain how to store the "page-title" in mysql and most importantly how to call it in php... Can someone shed some light on it please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly want, maybe you want `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]`?

Comment: What have you got so far? Which CMS producing these urls now?

Comment: If you already have the page-title in the URL, I am not sure there is any real benefit to removing the ID. Take a look at StackOverflow URLs, and they rank very well. Is there a good reason other than aesthetics for removing the ID?

Comment: @fabrik: No CMS, it's just a basic custom site. This is how I call the URLs now:
'$Links .= '<li><a href="http://mysite.com/' . $pid . '/' . $url . '">' . $linklabel . '</a></li>'

The URL stores the userfriendly urls, pid is pid.
@DanSingerman: just would like to make it number free, don't really care about ranking

Comment: I would be very careful about storing urls in the database.  That means every single URL you output will need a database query to resolve.  I becomes a massive bottleneck for your application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i will do this.

in the mysql i will add another row called `page_title` with `varchar(250) unique` and in that transform the title of the article into the page_title format using a function like

```
function convert_title($title){
    $title = preg_replace ("~[^a-zA-Z0-9]~", " ", $title);
    $title = preg_replace ("~\s+~", "-", $title);
    $title = substr($title, 0, 225);
    $i = 0;
    do{
        $exists = title_duplicate_check ($title);
        $i++;
    }while ($exists);

    if ( $i > 1) $title .= "_" . $i;

    return $title;
}

function title_duplicate_check ($title){
    //check if the title exists or not 
}
```

and then when the page is requested i will fetch the title from url and check for the title using `post_title` same as you now using `id`. Since the `post_title` is unique now you will have no problem working using this.

Hope it helps

Comment: so do I need to replace this part of my code? /* Determine which page ID to use in our query below */
if (!$_GET['p']) {
 $pageid = '1';

} else {
 $pageid = $_GET['p'];
}and if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

The way it usually works is by using rewrite rules (based on what server you use, but usually it's Apache and nginx has similar thing implemented).

Basically, if someone requests for /some-page, Apache internally rewrites it to /your_script.php?some_field_in_db=some-page

Reason I'm mentioning this is that I confirm that you're using the same thing before going into further explanation :)

Ok, now for the other bit - you want to hide the ID from your page URL. That means you rely on your "page-title" as the key in the database (assuming that your rewrite rules work when you remove the '1' from URL).

What you need to do is add unique index on the page_title column in your db table (or whatever the column is called if you have it) and you've to look up the contents of the page based on that key rather than ID.

Now, if you require the means of obtaining that 'page-title' from the URL - that's another question in itself and requires a bit more explanation on your side.